# Visual Studio didn't recognize code file encoding

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, encoding

We have an project with cyrilic comments. One of our team members have problem with cyrilic symbols. Visual Studio isn't recognize this symbols well and displays some unreadable symbols. We changed current language for non-Unicode programs in windows settings, but this didn't help. Any clues?

UPD
Just got news - windows was reinstalled and now visual studio works well.

Comment: Did you try `File->Advanced Save Options->Encoding`?

Comment: Roger, I didn't get how is it going to help with opening files. If encoding wasn't recognized correct then saving with another encoding will corrupt file

Comment: We had similar problems when converting all of our code to Unicode. In some cases, it was necessary to change the encoding of the file when saved (i.e. do a Save As with different encoding), to ensure that the correct BOM was written to the source. This is just a suggestion, therefore a comment rather than an answer. You *did* ask for "clues" ;-)

Comment: _One of our team members_  - when it does work for the others, find the difference in settings. One option is to save them from a working VS and then import. See Tools | Import and Export settings... Oth it might be a Windows setting.

Comment: Guys, thank for your input! Team member reinstalled windows and now it works well